# MultiTable SQL query. (MAX) on new table field hangs the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, progress-db

I am using BIDS to connect to a Progress DB through an ODBC connection:
This query works fine

```
SELECT     
PUB."master"."app-number", 
...
PUB."property"."prop-id",

FROM
PUB."master" master JOIN PUB."property" property ON
master."lt-acnt" = property."lt-acnt"
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB."arm" arm ON
master."lt-acnt" = arm."lt-acnt"

WHERE
...
```

However, I need to add some additional fields from another table.  The problem is that I only need the information from the last time these new fields were updated.

I have tried:

```
SELECT
yt."app-number"
...
yt."disc-adj-tot",
yt."rt-adj-nbr",
yt."base-disc-per"

FROM (
  SELECT  PUB."master"."app-number", 
  ...
  PUB."lt-rt-adj-hdr"."disc-adj-tot",
  PUB."lt-rt-adj-hdr"."rt-adj-nbr",
  PUB."lt-rt-adj-hdr"."base-disc-per"

  FROM PUB."master" master JOIN PUB."property" property ON
  master."lt-acnt" = property."lt-acnt"
  ...
  JOIN PUB."lt-rt-adj-hdr" lt_rt_adj_hdr ON
  lt_master."lt-acnt" = lt_rt_adj_hdr."lt-acnt") yt

INNER JOIN(
SELECT "app-number",
MAX("rt-adj-nbr") "rt-adj-nbr"
FROM (  PUB."lt-master" lt_master JOIN 
    PUB."lt-rt-adj-hdr" lt_rt_adj_hdr  ON
    lt_master."lt-acnt" = lt_rt_adj_hdr."lt-acnt")
GROUP BY "app-number") ss on yt."app-number" = ss."app-number" and 
yt."rt-adj-nbr" = ss."rt-adj-nbr"

WHERE ...
```

This query just hangs and will not return results unless a very simple WHERE clause like "WHERE yt."app-number" = 123456" is used.  I am completely stuck.

Comment: If you run it directly against progress without using BIDS, do you get results?  How long does it take?  This "hanging" could be a simple case of slow query and impatience.

Comment: This shocks me : FROM (((((((((((((     how far nested are your subqueries that you need that many opening brackets in your from clause?  Good chance this isn't 'hanging', it's just structured in a way causing it to have a multi-hour run time.

Comment: @DanBracuk long story short I don't have direct access to the progress db.  I have to use BIDS and connect via ODBC.  I have let the query go for a couple of hours without a result.

Comment: @Twelfth.  I rewrote the FROM clause and removed all of the ( with no luck.  While it was ugly and unnecessary it did work in the initial query.  It's when I add the new table with the INNER JOIN and MAX("rt-adj-nbr") information that I have the issues.

Comment: Has the owner of the Progress DB ever run "update statistics"?  The Progress SQL query optimizer needs to have good statistics in order to execute efficiently.  Progress applications usually use the 4GL engine rather than SQL so, in many cases, the administrator is not keeping the SQL statistics updated.  Which often leads to very poor SQL query performance.

Answer (score 1):

Has the owner of the Progress DB ever run "update statistics"? The Progress SQL query optimizer needs to have good statistics in order to execute efficiently. Progress applications usually use the 4GL engine rather than SQL so, in many cases, the administrator is not keeping the SQL statistics updated. Which often leads to very poor SQL query performance.

From the 4GL side the admin can use this script to generate a program that will do the job:

```
/* genUpdateSQL.p
 *
 * mpro dbName -p util/genUpdateSQL.p -param "tmp/updSQLstats.sql"
 *
 * sqlexp -user userName -password passWord -db dnName -S servicePort -infile tmp/updSQLstats.sql -outfile tmp/updSQLtats.log
 *
 */

output to value( ( if session:parameter <> "" then session:parameter else "updSQLstats.sql" )).

for each _file no-lock where _hidden = no:

  put unformatted
     "UPDATE TABLE STATISTICS AND INDEX STATISTICS AND ALL COLUMN STATISTICS FOR PUB."
     '"' _file._file-name '"' ";"
    skip
  .
  put unformatted "commit work;" skip.

end.

output close.

return.
```

Or, you could do it if you have sufficient privileges (just plug in your table name for _file._file-name).